# Securing neo4j database using neo4jclient

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have a neo4j database which is hosted on Amaozon EC2. I have created a C# application which used neo4jclient to read and update the neo4j database on Amazon server.

In amazon I had to open 7474 port on which neo4j server is listening so that my c# application can interact with it

How can I secure my neo4j server so that only my client can update the neo4j db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the neo4j-server.properties configuration file, there you can define which IP addresses can communicate with it.

Additionally you could also look at [this](http://www.delimited.io/blog/2014/1/15/getting-started-with-neo4j-on-ubuntu-server) and [this](http://nikolas.demiridis.gr/post/51149977942/neo4j-install-on-ubuntu-lazy-admin-way)

or 
 try [this](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension) extension

hope one of them will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Kiran. I do not want to define to which IP addresses can communicate as the UI will be used by people who are behind NAT. I will look at other options mentioned and will update.